# Multiple notification by NotificationManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-statusbar

Currently I notifying user as -

```
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name",1212,notification);
```

This is working nicely. But it shows only one icon in status bar, though I sent multiple notification on different times.

I would like to show icon for each notification (i.e. 3 icons).

I am not sure whether it's possible. Any clue?

Comment: Are you using the same notificationId for all of them?

Comment: do you want to generate all notification or for a particular type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name",(int)(Math.random() * 101),notification);
```

*same id on notification change always the last one

*different id create a new notification

Comment: Using a counter that you increment each time is even better

Answer (score 1):

According to [notify documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification)) if you want always the same 3 notifications all the time try using unique tags. It's the combination of tag and id that makes the notification "overwrite" the previous one.

```
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name 1",1212,notification);
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name 2",1212,notification);
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name 3",1212,notification);
```

or

```
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name",1212,notification);
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name",1213,notification);
mNotificationManager.notify("My App Name",1214,notification);
```